# Google Maps v3: large size for markers

Tags: google-maps

I need to display markers on my map and it's working well. The only problem is that they appear to be too small. How can I make sure that the markers used are large in size and can be visible from almost any zoom state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your using version 3 of the api-

When you create the marker, in the marker options you can specify the icon like this:

```
icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
         url:string, size?:Size, 
         origin?:Point, anchor?:Point, scaledSize?:Size
      )
```

Set size to the actual size of your icon image. 
Set scaledSize to whatever size you want to stretch the image to.

It is better of cause to make an icon image the size you want instead of scaling it.

Answer (score 10):

For making the icons bigger I would definitely recommend to make your icon images larger. To for example fix pixely icons on high-dpi mobile device using downscaled hi-res icons use following code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
    map: map,
    icon: {
        url: "img/img.png",
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32) // pixels
    }
});
```

Tested with Google Maps API JavaScript v3.13