# Change marker size in Google maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095574/google-maps-api-3-custom-marker-color-for-default-dot-marker/7686977#7686977) of how to color a google maps marker by setting the icon using a [MarkerImage](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage), and the coloring works well.  But I can't make the scaledSize argument change the size of the marker.

```
    var pinColor = 'FFFF00';
    var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34),
        new google.maps.Size(2, 4));
    marker.setIcon(pinIcon);
```

What is the correct use of the scaledSize argument to change the marker size?  For example, how can I double the marker size?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This answer expounds on [John Black's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3/7845077#7845077), so I will repeat some of his answer content in my answer.

The easiest way to resize a marker seems to be leaving argument 2, 3, and 4 null and scaling the size in argument 5.

```
var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FFFF00",
    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
    new google.maps.Size(42, 68)
);
```

As an aside, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662379/large-gmaps-v3-markers/5665073#5665073) to a similar question asserts that defining marker size in the 2nd argument is better than scaling in the 5th argument.  I don't know if this is true.

Leaving arguments 2-4 null works great for the default google pin image, but you must set an anchor explicitly for the default google pin shadow image, or it will look like this:

[image: what happens when you leave anchor null on an enlarged shadow]

The bottom center of the pin image happens to be collocated with the tip of the pin when you view the graphic on the map.  This is important, because the marker's position property (marker's [LatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) position on the map) will automatically be collocated with the visual tip of the pin when you leave the anchor (4th argument) `null`.  In other words, leaving the anchor null ensures the tip points where it is supposed to point.

However, the tip of the shadow is not located at the bottom center.  So you need to set the 4th argument explicitly to offset the tip of the pin shadow so the shadow's tip will be colocated with the pin image's tip.

By experimenting I found the tip of the shadow should be set like this: x is 1/3 of size and y is 100% of size.

```
var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
    null,
    null,
    /* Offset x axis 33% of overall size, Offset y axis 100% of overall size */
    new google.maps.Point(40, 110), 
    new google.maps.Size(120, 110));
```

to give this:

[image: offset the enlarged shadow anchor explicitly]

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the aspect ratio in `google.maps.Size`, or to specify percentages instead of actual pixels? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to re-scale the default marker icon? That is, can I change the scaling of a marker _without_ having to use `setIcon` on the marker?

Answer (score 25):

The size arguments are in pixels.  So, to double your example's marker size the fifth argument to the MarkerImage constructor would be:

```
new google.maps.Size(42,68)
```

I find it easiest to let the map API figure out the other arguments, unless I need something other than the bottom/center of the image as the anchor.  In your case you could do:

```
var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
    new google.maps.Size(42, 68)
);
```