# Documentation for Google maps MarkerImage url string in constructor

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-visualization, google-maps-markers

The first argument of the [google.maps.MarkerImage](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage) class constructor is a url string with several GET variables.

[image]

[This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3/7852357#7852357) of the url string in use.  The color variable is clear, but what do the other variables do?

Comment: Wow, first time I've been voted down for a question.  Would the voter care to comment why this is a bad question?  I didn't know it was a Google Charts API url, and I didn't see any mention of google charts in the google maps documentation concerning this argument.  I think it's legitimate for someone to use the Google maps api without having any experience with the Google charts api.

Comment: Over the past year this question has received 744 views, which is more than 2 views per day on average during that year.  So obviously the question helped someone - but I still get a down vote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what Trott says.  Basically the markerimage URL is a relative or absolute url to an image, nothing more or less.  So depending on where you get your images from, it might have a querystring on it (e.g. if the marker is to be dynamically generated by a server-side script).  So in this case you just happen to be using the Charts API to get a dynamic image for your marker.

Comment: Yea, Chart API was the part I was missing.  Not sure how I could have worded it differently to avoid the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is not necessarily a URL string with several GET parameters.  It is simply a URL string.  Google Maps API uses that URL to retrieve the image.  If there are GET parameters, they are used (or ignored) by the server from which the image is being retrieved.

The example you link to contains a URL using Google's Charts API.  The definitions for the parameters are at http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_params.html.