# Google Maps - Change layer icon size

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an issue where I am trying to create a hover effect using Google maps where you hover over a div on the right, and a corresponding map marker will increase in size.  I am trying to use techniques discussed, here: [Change marker size in Google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3/7845077#7845077),

but that is not really that helpful because it's constructing a new marker.  I just would like to scale my existing marker up.  I am trying to do something like this:

```
var aMap = $container.googleMapClient("map");
var layer = aMap.layers[iconLayer];
layer.points[iconLayer].marker.getIcon().size = new google.maps.Size(45,33);
```

but unfortunately, this is not changing the visible size.  If I inspect the layer at runtime, the size is indeed changed.  Is this type of behavior not allowed like this?  Do I really have to destroy the layer and render a larger one, and then on mouseout do the opposite?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create two different markerImages, one default an one for hover. (Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MarkerImage )
2. Swap markerImage on hover using google.maps.Marker.setIcon() (Docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Marker )

Here is an example, how to use markerImages: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

marker.getIcon().size is readonly, so you can not set a new size here. And google.maps.Size(45,33) will not strech your image to the new size, but only change the clipping of the your image.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.  I was just coming here to write pretty much this answer.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `scaledSize` attribute on [MarkerImage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage).

As LeJared said, you'll need to create two different `MarkerImage` objects, and swap between them.

`MarkerImage` objects are immutable, so you won't be able to change the sizing on the fly. More generally in the Maps API, properties need to be set using the set() function, otherwise the update won't be seen by the API.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @gabaum10 Could you please share your code , how did you rescale marker image ?