# Change Google Marker Size on Google Maps

Tags: php, google-maps

I have the following code that builds a custom google map marker like this:

```
            mapa.markers[ind] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: mposition,
                                map:mapa.map,
                                title:mapa.json.markers[ind].timestamp,
                                icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="+ind+"|000000|FFF",
                            });
```

Using this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3), I am trying to integrate this code into the above but am getting a syntax error?  What am I doing wrong?

```
null, /* size is determined at runtime */
null, /* origin is 0,0 */
null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
new google.maps.Size(42, 68)
```

Here is the updated code that shows a syntax error:

```
 mapa.markers[ind] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: mposition,
                                    map:mapa.map,
                                    title:mapa.json.markers[ind].timestamp,
                                    icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="+ind+"|000000|FFF",
                                    null, /* size is determined at runtime */
                                    null, /* origin is 0,0 */
                                    null, /* anchor is bottom center of the scaled image */
                                    new google.maps.Size(42, 68)
                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.

An [icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) should be defined like this:

```
mapa.markers[ind] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: mposition,
         map:mapa.map,
         title:mapa.json.markers[ind].timestamp,
         icon: {url:"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="+ind+"|000000|FFF",
         scaledSize:new google.maps.Size(42, 68)}
});
```

(credit to @andrewap for testing it and the jsfiddle)

The `size` property is not needed (it is automatically set when the image loads), unless you're using sprites, which is not the case here.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fUEDh/

Comment: The `size` property is not needed (it is automatically set when the image loads), unless you're using sprites, which is not the case here.