# Changing Marker Size in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change the marker size, and no matter how I try they just disappear. I've tried this:

`scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(100, 68)`

```
var marker;
addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");
var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
//Create a new marker and info window
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: lat,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|000000|FFF',
    content: addressDetails[0]
});
markersArray.push(marker);
```

Comment: [Change marker size in Google maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3) is obsolete. The MarkerImage class has been deprecated (is no longer listed anywhere in the official Google documentation as any versions that contained it are no longer served) and replaced with the [google.maps.Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) object.  However the principle is the same, just use an anonymous object as defined in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers for future reference

```
new google.maps.Size(42,68)
```

42 and 86 are pixel values. Those will scale the marker to whatever you want.

Source:
[Change marker size in Google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3)