# Change Custom Marker Size Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I managed set a custom icon for the image marker (url of icon is in code), but I have no idea how to customize its size. I've looked around for help online, but due to my very limited coding knowledge, have not been able to add the code needed to make it work. Can someone send me the complete, finished code with the modification needed to customize width/height for the market icon?

Thank you!

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyDL51DzuRotMkfR09g540u2dZHlKPMpR54'></script>
<div style='overflow:hidden;height:450px;width:100%;'>
<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:450px;width:100%;'></div>
<style>
#gmap_canvas img {
  max-width:none!important;
  background:none!important
}
</style>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function init_map(){
  var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false, 
    draggable: false, 
    zoom:16,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(25.841211,-80.308539),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.841211,-80.308539),
    icon: 'http://www.ssglobalsupply.com/images/location-contact.png'
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'6891 NW 74th St Medley, FL 33166<br>'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: What size do you want it to be?  Have you looked at the documentation on [icon sizing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon)?  Also, see this example:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Comment: I have looked at many things but I am implementing the code wrong. If it would be possible to send the complete finished code with the addition for sizing. I'l like it to be 50px by 50px

Comment: Post what you have that isn't working, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: I added "new google.maps.Size(42,68)" after the url for the icon image.

Comment: So, icon: 'http://www.ssglobalsupply.com/images/location-contact.png',new google.maps.Size(42,68)});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size arguments are in pixels. So, to double your example's marker size the fifth argument to the MarkerImage constructor would be:

```
    new google.maps.Size(42,68)
```

Check the link for [steampowered's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842730/change-marker-size-in-google-maps-v3/7845077#7845077) to get more details

---

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pGBZD/788/) for your icon marker size 50px x 50px

```
      var image = {
      url: 'http://www.ssglobalsupply.com/images/location-contact.png',
      // This marker is 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels high.
      size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
      // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
    };
```

Comment: When I add this line of code the the script, the map does not show in anyway anymore. I am likely adding it wrong. Can you send me the full code with this snippet of code added in the right spot? Thank you

Comment: did you have &callback=init_map into the script function?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The fiddle you sent has nothing to do with my question though. I simply want to be able to modify the size custom marker icon in my code. Can you send me a fiddle with the code I posted and the additional needed code to modify the icon size? That would be perfect

Comment: All you  need to do is make a var img as my edit answer, and have size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50). Then you point your marker which is icon: image

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am having trouble implementing this into my code. I have VERY little programming knowledge. Can you possibly make a fiddle with the code I posted above and the modification? I will vote your answer

Comment: The new JFIDDLE in my answer is your map. Check the answer about http://jsfiddle.net/pGBZD/788/

Comment: Yes it works great. Thank you so much. I had to change it to scaledSize, because the way you had it, it cropped instead. Last question...in my original code the address was showing by default. In your JSFiddle, I have to click the marker for the address to show. Do you know what I should add to have the address showing by default?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pGBZD/789/ here is the one that has it open automatically. In my previous JSFIDDLE, I had it open on click (the last 4 lines of code). You can compare 2 JSFIDDLE files to see the differences

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great